# How does requestAnimationFrame really work?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The official document says `The method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked before the repaint.` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

I wrote a simple code below:

```html
<html>
    <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background: #999"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let count = 0;
        function step() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.marginLeft = `${count ++}px`
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
        }
        step()
    </script>
</html>
```

My question is how to understand `before the repaint`? And why it works?

1. Can we just divide the running process of browser to `repainting` and `before repainting`, and `requestAnimationFrame` just avoid the callback invoked in painting process?
2. When browser repaint caused by the step, and the step will be invoked before the next repaint, but the repaint actually caused by the step. Is it paradox?

Comment: The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation.

Comment: -- from the [exactly same page you post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: and what you mean by `invoke repaint`?

Comment: like you change the background of an element, this will invoke repainting in browser.

Comment: @ CodeAlien, no it'd only *pending* a repaint afaict.

Comment: @appleapple I revised my question above, can u help me answer the questions?

Comment: @ CodeAlien what do you mean by *`requestAnimationFrame` just avoid the callback invoked in painting process*?

Comment: to summarize, **all** painting are scheduled, you **cannot force** a repaint to happens (in standard js, afaict).

Comment: @appleapple but we know there are repaint and reflow in browser, if background changed, it will cause repaint, right? https://medium.com/swlh/what-the-heck-is-repaint-and-reflow-in-the-browser-b2d0fb980c08

Comment: @ CodeAlien more likely it'll cause browser to repaint **at the next (paint) cycle**.

Comment: correct wordings: 1: you cannot force a repaint to happens **immediately** 2. more likely it'll cause browser to repaint at the next paint **stage**.

Answer (score 1):

1. and 2. - you can looks like fantasy of steps s1,s2...:

s1
browser want to start the  repainting of "main repainting" of page - like a background comparatively to the callback function

s2
before this "main" repainting browser perform "calculated part of repaint" call back function on the timeline of future "main repainting"

s3
browser start to work repaint and do in parallel: background="main repainting" and  "calculated part of repaint" on the one same timeline.

to perform the step s3 browser must to "calculate before" because code of callback function is custom that code of background of main page